# Modulo prime close to the power of 2 algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary

I found an algorithm in [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/what-are-the-computational-benefits-of-primes-close-to-the-power-of-2):

> After a multiplication you have a number with 2 · 255 bits. Since 2<sup>255</sup> = 19 (mod *q*), you can take the upper half, multiply it by 19 and add it to the lower half. This gives you an equivalent number smaller than 20 · 2<sup>255</sup>. Repeat this to get a number that's smaller than 2 · *q*. Now check if the value is greater or equal to *q* and subtract *q*.

Can someone help me finding the name of this algorithm?

Comment: Try https://math.stackexchange.com perhaps?

Comment: It's basically long division base 2^255, but it underestimates the quotient in the first two steps for speed (as in the long division variant that educators call "scaffolding").